# Does order matter when subtracting systems of linear equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say I have a simple system like so:

\begin{cases}
    2x - y = 1\\
    x - y = 2\\
\end{cases}

Why does it not matter what equation is being subtracted from the other when it comes to getting solutions. The answers are the same, irrespective of which equation is being subtracted from the other. Why does this work? My confusion stems from the fact that a-b is not the same as b-a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is that, if $a-b=c$, then $-(a-b)=-c$, or, rather, $b-a=-c$.  Basically by reversing the order in which you subtract the two, you get the same result, just now with everything multiplied by $-1$, which is perfectly fine.

Indeed, we see that subtracting the bottom from the top yields $x=-1$ in your example. If we subtract the top from the bottom instead, we obtain $-x=1$ instead, which gives $x=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=B$ and $C=D$ then $A-C=B-D$ and $C-A=D-B$, are the same.